# Sentry sourcemaps not working for Expo 49 builds

Tags: expo, sentry, source-maps

I had a script that ran

```
eas update --branch <DEVELOPMENT> --non-interactive --auto --json
```

and then called sentry-cli `upload-sourcemaps` to upload output of `eas update` to sentry.

However, it stopped working after upgrading to expo 49 because `eas update` produces `.hbc` files instead of js bundle as before.

Any ideas on how to get sentry sourcemaps working again with Hermes?

I have tried following the guide from  https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/manual-setup/hermes/

and then run the `eas update` with `--skip-bundler` option, but the over-the-air update was not applied.
I assume that's because it was build not the way expo wants it.
That's when I thought there must be a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to get this set up on a new project altogether starting with Expo 49. Running `eas update` produces a `dist` folder, and in that `dist` folder, I get bundles for `<platform>-<update-id>.hbc` as well as `<platform>-<update-id>.map`.

Changing the `.hbc` file name to `index.android.bundle` and then running the `sentry-cli upload-sourcemaps` command with the correct dist and ID got sourcemaps uploaded correctly—e.g.,

```
node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli releases \
    files <release name> \
    upload-sourcemaps --org <org-slug> --project <project-slug> \
    --dist <Android Update ID> \
    --rewrite \
    dist/bundles/index.android.bundle dist/bundles/android-<hash>.map
```

Edit: I have only tested this with Android so far, but I presume changing the file name for the iOS bundle and then running the `sentry-cli upload-sourcemaps` command will produce similar results.

Edit again: Tested and confirmed this works on iOS! Just rename the outputted `ios-<hash>.hbc` -> `main.jsbundle` and use the recommended template for the iOS sourcemaps:

```
node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli releases \
    files <${bundleIdentifier}@${version}+${buildNumber}> \
    upload-sourcemaps --org <org-slug> --project <project-slug> \
    --dist <iOS Update ID> \
    --rewrite \
    dist/bundles/main.jsbundle dist/bundles/ios-<hash>.map
```

Comment: thank you, this gave me some confidence that something was off in my setup and i got it working! :)

I also had map files named in the format `ios/android-<hash>.map` before
but now I got it working with `main.jsbundle.map` / `index.android.bundle.map` 
in the [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/sourcemaps/) they are also named like that. 

One more thing that was confusing me was that uploaded bundle files were sized at 0 bytes in sentry, but apparently, that's expected.